# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket

Tags: magento-1.9

There has been an error processing your request

Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 174749344571

```
 #1 /var/www/html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(320): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#2 /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(460): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#3 /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#4 /var/www/html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#5 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(169): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SET NAMES utf8')
#6 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(110): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection('pdo_mysql', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#7 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(141): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_setup')
#8 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(234): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->__construct('core_setup')
#9 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(417): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#10 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#11 /var/www/html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#12 /var/www/html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#13 {main}";s:3:"url";s:6:"/admin";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your local.xml under app/etc to verify your Database connections.